# Array is not cloned, wrapped inside Proxy

Tags: vue.js

Im executing this code inside vue created() method:

```js
        const width = window.innerWidth;
        const columns = this.columns.slice()
        let colVis = columns.map((element) => {
                if(element.sClass == 'min-tv' && width < 2500) {
                    element.visible = false;
                    return element;
                } else if(element.sClass == 'min-desktop-lg' && width < 1980) {
                    element.visible = false;
                    return element;
                } else {
                    return element;
                }
            });
        console.log(columns);
        console.log(colVis);
```

For some reason both arrays returns same values (and this.columns too).
Everything is wraped inside Proxy - arrays and their values.

I cant understand whats going on and why i can't have clone of array?

I don't use computed, because it's initialization values (for Datatables colvis).

Answer (score 1):

You should use `filter` to filter data from an array.

```js
           const width = window.innerWidth;
          const columns = this.columns.slice()
          let colVis = columns.map((element) => {
                  if(element.sClass == 'min-tv' && width < 2500) {
                    element.visible = false;
                    return element;
                  } else if(element.sClass == 'min-desktop-lg' && width < 1980) {
                    element.visible = false;
                    return element;
                } else {
                    return element;
                }
            }).filter((element) => element.visible);
        console.log(columns);
        console.log(colVis);
```

Comment: Changes are still applied to columns array too.

Comment: visible property changes will reflect both arrays because you are changing object value.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be vue bug.
Using inline `window.innerWidth` breaks its normal behavior.